Replacing letters in a string with numbers
I'm working on query that includes strings that is a combination of letters and numbers, something that looks like this
'1A234',AB234'.

What I need to do is to convert the letters in the strings into numbers and replace them back into the string. For example, the string '1A234' will be converted to '165234'.
It can be done using REPLACE but I could only do it like this.
REPLACE(REPLACE('AB123','A',CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varbinary,'A'))),'B',CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varbinary,'B')))

Since the REPLACE value will be 2 char, so I can't just use TRANSLATE.
I would like to know if there's any other way to make it much shorter, since I would have to write this REPLACE for every alphabet not just A and B, or is this the only way to do it without creating some sort of stored procedure?
I am only performing a simple SELECT query for a report I'm working on and this is one of the column I need to deal with, so was wondering if it could be done more efficiently without using a stored procedure.

Unfortunately, nested REPLACE calls might be the best you can do with a pure query (sans a SP or something simliar).  You could also consider cleaning up your data outside the database, before you bring it into SQL Server.

@TimBiegeleisen That's unfortunate,I guess I will have to go along with the nested 'REPLACE' than,It was originally a local report processed from C# using for loop,so I was thinking of something similar or just try to deal with it through program and just load the output file from SQL or something , but I guess that would just become way to complicated for such simple job,might as well just get back using 'REPLACE'.

A regex approach which might be available in C# would be to do a regex find all replace on letters with a callback function.  In the callback function, you can map each letter to its digit ASCII code.

Side note - Do you need a 1-to-1 mapping to maintains uniqueness? Your current algorithm might map "AB6768" and "6566CD" both to the same value - "65666768".

@TN So the data have a unique identity before it marking them as different unit, something like "A-B1234",I can substring and join the "A" with another table to get the unit's name,with the "B1234" being the unit's number which I have to convert myself,not sure why the client store the number part using part alphabet part number,but from what I understand they are indeed the same value.

You can explode out the string into component characters and perform conditional logic per character then re aggregate it. DB Fiddle.
The below currently replaces with the ASCII code for upper case A-Z and the  original character for all other characters.
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(8000) = '1A234' 


SELECT STRING_AGG(
        IIF(ASCII(Ch) BETWEEN 65 AND 90, CAST(ASCII(Ch) AS VARCHAR(2)), Ch),
        ''
        ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value)
FROM generate_series(1,LEN(@String))
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@String,value,1)))V(ch)

The above assumes SQL Server 2022 for generate_series - if that is not available you can join onto some other source of sequential numbers instead.

Exactly what I'm looking for,thank you : D Change it a bit to ISNUMERIC(Ch)=0 THEN CAST（ASCII(Ch)) AS VARCHAR(2) and works really well for me.

@Vic917 - ISNUMERIC will also return 1 for characters like . and $. If you want to leave digits alone and transform any other character you can use IIF(ASCII(Ch) BETWEEN 48 AND 57, Ch, CAST(ASCII(Ch) AS VARCHAR(3)))

If this answer helped you then do not forget to upvote the answer as well as accept it.  +1 from me.
